# modx TV access checkbox is not available

Tags: wamp, modx, modx-revolution

I have installed on my windows machine Denwer, and installed there MODX Revolution 2.2.10-pl, but i have troubles:
 when i create TV and try to configure him, but column, where must checkboxes didn't have any checkbox, how can then i select on which template what i have?

also i didn't have some icons in manager.

Now all is looking so:

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59666091/tv.PNG]

and i didn't know how to solve it(

Comment: You have problem with css files. Dont know why without any other information. Maybe update modx to 2.2.11 solve this issue.

Comment: @Vasis what kind of info do you mean? and how can i update without changing anything?